# Why am I getting reset every time I go into Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

Every time I go into Geometry Dash using my Amazon Fire, I get all my progress reset. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been a big topic on the GD wiki:

### Are you using an restricted account? People have reported progress resets with a restricted account. If you are using one, try switching to a regular account.

Also, try saving your game before exiting it. Don't just press the home button after playing.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Reddit. I've verified it works!!

https://www.reddit.com/r/geometrydash/comments/5ovsfa/21_on_android_asks_me_to_login_everytime_i_open_it/

EDIT: SOLVED! I had the game installed inside Android's Adoptable Storage, which (in Android 6.0+) means basically I had the game installed on the SD Card. Geometry Dash 2.1 broke adoptable storage compatibility. Moving the game back to internal storage and doing login + load solved the issue.